# tunneling x11vnc through ssh on a non standard port to ubuntu computer tightvnc

Tags: ssh, vnc, vncviewer

I have been stuck with setting up my virtual desktop on my ubuntu laptop. I am running ubuntu to ubuntu with x11vnc I start the process on my laptop as follows:

```
ssh -L5904:localhost:5900 -p Port remoteuser@remoteip
```

That command works, then I start x11vnc server,

```
x11vnc -noncache -once -shared -rfbauth ~/.vnc/passwd
```

This command works and starts connection. Then I open another window on my laptop and type,

```
export VNC_VIA_CMD='/usr/bin/ssh -2 -c aes128-cbc -x -p Port -l User -f -: %L:%H:%R %G sleep 20'
```

(not sure if works). then I type,

```
vncviewer -endcodings Tight -depth 8 -quality 1 -via IPofremotemachine -u remoteuser localhost:01
```

The first time it worked but from now on it just gives me the `vncviewer -help` screen everytime. I type in the password for my remote machine and then shows -help screen for vncviewer.

I think the problem is with Tightvnc viewer but don't know what. Please help. I got some info on www.vanemery.com/Linux/VNC/vnc-over-ssh.html‎.

Comment: This is a bit off topic, but ... FreeNX is faster, also tunnels over ssh, and IMO is a better option. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX

Comment: (originally posted as an answer by [TomC](http://askubuntu.com/users/169949/tomc)) When you are typing the commands, are you typing exactly what you've shown, or are you inserting actual values for "Port", "User", "remoteuser", and "remoteip"? For example:

`ssh -L5904:localhost:5900 -p 5555 joe@192.168.1.100`

then

`export VNC_VIA_CMD='/usr/bin/ssh -2 -c aes128-cbc -x -p 5555 -l joe -f` (and so on) Also check out http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/#tunnelling for more information.

Comment: Yes I don't just type port it represents the port number and so on

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. for the x11vnc command I typed `-nevershared -forever` instead of `-once -shared` did not do the `export` command and just typed

```
vncviewer -encodings tight localhost::5904
```

and that did it but no password (strange `-rfbauth`).